# Rails: PointOfSale expected, got String error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, submit

i'm a little noob to rails.. and i'm trying to submit a hidden field with id ..

here is the hidden field:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :point_of_sale  %>
```

and the parameters that came out of submitting is like the following:

```
"venue"=>{"point_of_sale"=>"9"}, "commit"=>"Update Venue", "id"=>"1"}
```

but it gives me error:

```
PointOfSale  expected, got String error
```

what is the problem then?

Comment: Are you getting this error after submitting form? can u post more about the errors?

Comment: You should have `point_of_sale_id`

Comment: it's happen after submitting the form it's a Typemissmatch exception.... but that's all about it

Comment: @MichaelSzyndel i have point_of_sale_id in database

Comment: <%= f.hidden_field :point_of_sale_id  %>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to save id, than you should pass point_of_sale_id in you hidden field :-

```
<%= f.hidden_field :point_of_sale_id  %>
```

Hope this helps.